# PHP - API GMAIL - check if user exists

Tags: php, api, gmail, php-7, php-5.5

I am trying to create users in gmail via API and I do it through this code where I pass an object of type user and do the following (this code works)

```
<?php
$scopes = implode(' ', [
    Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER
]);


try {
    $file = '/home/test/confing/test.json';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('test');
    $client->setScopes($scopes);
    $client->setSubject($user->email);
    $client->setAuthConfig($file);
}
catch (\Exception $exception) {
    dump($exception->getMessage());
    die();
}


$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

$userObj = new Google_Service_Directory_User(
    array(
        "name" => array("givenName" => "{$user->name}", "familyName" => "{$user->first_name}"),
        "primaryEmail" => "{$user->email}",
        "password" => sha1("123456789")
    )
);


$newUser = $service->users->insert($userObj);
$createdUser = $newUser->primaryEmail;
?>
```

The problem I have, that before creating the user I would like to make an API call to check if the user exists and I do not know how to do it. Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the user exists I think you'll get an error when you try to add them. Just catch that error.

Comment: It's possible to do a call with php library.. trying to get if user exists first?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users

Comment: Use `$service->users->list()` to list the users with the desired username.